# (node:13606) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object] - Ionic Framework

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with the Ionic Framework in its 3rd version, and when I run `ionic cordova build --release android`, I get this error :

```
(node:13791) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:13791) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Other threads about this didn't lead me anywhere. Please help

Answer (score 1):

my first attempt would be to check my code for an unhandled promise rejection.

How can i dectect a unhandled promise rejection?

assuming we have a code like this:

```
asyncAction.then(success => {
 // do stuff with the result of success
})
```

so if the asyncActions fails, there is an unhandled promise rejection because we never catch the rejection of the promise. To  catch the rejection we need to do this:

```
asyncAction.then(success => {
  // do stuff with the result of success
}, rejection => {
// handle action failed
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem downgrading cordova version to 7.1.0